Why RK3 is more stable than forward euler
I'm working on hyperbolic equations.
I implemented RK1 (Euler), RK2 and RK3 for the convection equation with a central scheme in space. For a smooth solution, I have a perfect solution while for RK1 it blows up. RK2 have some oscillations as I expect, but the quality of the solution is still "good"
I wonder why RK3 is perfect as I thought that the source of instabilities was mainly due to spatial discretization. How does it stabilizes ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Generic answer: Because the stability region is larger. While for order 1 it does not contain any semi-circle, for second order it almost contains a semi-circle of radius 2, and for third order a slightly larger one. This leads exactly to the described effects.
